Xubuntu Desktop 24.04 install with live usb, getting hung up at manual partitioning. Need to mount ext4 partition - how?
I have a laptop with Windows 10, one hard drive. I partitioned the drive (keeping Windows partition) with a swap and the main ext4 partition.
partitioned_hard_drive
Started to install Xubuntu from live usb. Chose manual partitioning.
manual_installation
I set ext4 to mount at root.
set_ext4_to_mount_at_root
At this point I cannot continue.
cannot_continue_install
The ext4 partition doesn't seem to be mounted. I tried some methods from similar questions, but I don't know where to mount.
Need help on this.
After Xubuntu installs, I assume that grub2 will automatically take over the boot up. And I will end up with something like this:
shim64
Any help is apriciated.
Grub2 error during install:
grub2_error

Providing release details is always helpful to ensure we provide advice specific to your system (Xubuntu currently has two supported installers; you look like you're using a ubuntu-desktop-installer ISO, but you don't specify release).  Your picture shows you providing a / partition, but I don't see a ESP or EFI System Partition being specified as required to get a uEFI system to boot. If your system is legacy its not required, but you being unable to continue is you not selecting the required ESP required by the EFI standard.

@ guiverc: sda1 is an EFI system partion from Windows. Do I need to point to it somehow? I also edited the release info.

Your ESP or EFI System Partition should be mounted as /boot/efi ; that location is enough to let the system know how to use it (ie. an ESP).

You don't mean to mount /dev/sda1 - the Windows ESP - as /boot/efi ? Or do I mount /dev/sda6 (ext4) as /boot/efi? How do I do that. Can you give me a terminal command?

I was suggesting you do it via the installer; it being why you "cannot continue install" issue you've not resolved.
